# CloundFront redirects request and removes query param

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an issue with CloudFront. I'm trying to make a request to the following URL:

```
https://xxxx/leaver/?sesame=L_E6dDGQS5aCe9pPcKJpFwI9W-JjMn4vxxxxx
```

CloudFront returns a 302 response for this route and cuts off the `sesame` parameter. This is the response:

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens and how I can change this behavior. My app depends on the `sesame` parameter.

I'd love some help with this. I'm happy to provide more info if needed.

**The app works fine locally.**

Comment: Looks like it's the origin that does the 302 redirect and strips off the query params. What kind of backend are you using as the origin?

Comment: This is actually a request to the font-end hosted with aws amplify console (react)

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks for your response! I'm also not sure if I'd see the behavior only in production if the origin would remove the param. But I'm super happy for any suggestion or idea you might have on this!